# Why are my vertices all disconnected?

Tags: vertices

I built a character using the mirror, skin, and surface smooth modifier, and when I was ready I applied visual geometry to mesh and deleted half the character, then re-added the mirror modifier so I could start sculpting the vertices directly.

At first each vertex moves normally, then suddenly its like all the vertices are disconnected from each other. The odd thing is that the edges and faces move normally, they warp as if they're connected, but the VERTEXES do not and this is the second character I've had this experience with.

I've tried merging vertices and this changes nothing. I wonder if perhaps they're not disconnected but I've accidentally toggled something that disconnects them when I move them?

Can anyone help? I'm also only about 3 days into using this program so I'm definitely a beginner. Thank you!

[image][image]

UPDATE: As of right now this isn't happening anymore. I reopened the file and everything was magically stuck back together, so I think it might be a bug of some kind. If it happens again I will upload the file. Thanks for your comments and advice.

UPDATE 2: I'm having the same problems! I'll upload the file so you can take a look at it, also uploading another image to show how every vertex seems to move independently. This seems to start when I select the whole mesh and write "merge by distance", suddenly everything is disconnected and **won't merge back together again**. What's happening?[image]

Comment: maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Any vertices I move seem disconnected, beyond the mirror. I've also just re-opened the program and file, and it doesn't seem to be doing this anymore. Must be a bug

Comment: Here's the file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6923" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6923/)

Comment: I notice it seems to happen right after I try and merge ANY vertices at all. Whether its by distance, at center, etc, suddenly all the vertices disconnect.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Linked file has all vertices connected. Tested on 2.82 alpha. Merge by Distance removed two vertices. Nothing strange happened. Sorry, but nicely weird :) What blender version you use?

Comment: The only one issue I see are 4 flipped faces on an intimate part of body, nothing more. Try to open Blender > File > Defaults > Load Factory Setting. Append this mesh into a new file and try to reproduce issue again. Or try it with different version of blender.

Comment: I  already delete that comment, but it came to my mind again - you wrote all vertices are disconnected, but that is not corect, vertices are still connected to three others. So what can be a rule to disconnect it that direction and not another? Hmm

Comment: Are you pressing V when you manipulate with vertex? Or did you manipulated with Keymap in preferences? I found Rip function that does exactly what happens to you. So in case you don't touch V key, then I can explain it just you have assign this Rip function to another key. Since you are totally new to blender, probably you tried another Keymap set than default and there can be some conflict ...

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not certain what process you went through that resulted in your edges being split wierdly, you should be able to fix all wierd verts on the model by selecting all, pressing Alt+M and selecting "By Distance". This merges vertices that are X distance from other vertices.

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work. The mesh acts like it's connected except for when I move a vertex. I've merged many vertex pairs only to find out that they're still somehow disconnected.

Comment: @Andrew Delange: As advised in Q comments - share your simplified .blend file with problematic mesh (in best - condition before you start to fix it).

Comment: Here's the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6923" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6923/)

Comment: I explained this above, I notice it seems to happen right after I try and merge ANY vertices at all. Whether its by distance, at center, etc, suddenly all the vertices disconnect. I uploaded a screenshot of a bunch of vertices being easily disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

**Separation by Rip** shortcut V
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#rip-region

Rip creates a “hole” in the mesh by making a copy of selected vertices and edges, still linked to the neighboring non-selected vertices, so that the new edges are borders of the faces on one side, and the old ones, borders of the faces on the other side of the rip.

[image][image]